# How calculate clock_timestamp in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, oracle, spring-boot

I'm trying to convert Oracle to PostgreSQL. To calculate expiry OTP am using below line but am getting error like **operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone + integer***. Please help me to solve this error.

```
for W_EXPIRY := clock_timestamp() + W_OTP_EXPIRY / 1440;
```

Comment: Use interval datatype instead: `select clock_timestamp() + (interval '1' minute)*10`

Comment: Why the tag for Java?

Comment: I want result to be stored in W_EXPIRY variable. how to do this in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can only add `interval` values to a `timestamp` or `timestamptz`. [`make_interval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#id-1.5.8.15.6.2.2.28.1.1.1) can be used to create an interval based on a column from the table:

```
clock_timestamp() + make_interval(mins => W_OTP_EXPIRY)
```

If the unit in `W_OTP_EXPIRY` is not minutes, then you need to use a different parameter, e.g. `days => W_OTP_EXPIRY` if those are days.